# Kivy: override default kivy.properties when creating a new one

Tags: python, kivy

In this example I'm adding a `ListProperty` with a default value. If I write a new value in `kv`
, it's keeping the default value instead of taking the new one. (here `text_list: ["Apple","Orange","Banana"]` should replace `text_list = ListProperty(["WHY  DEFAULT PARAMETER IS STILL HERE :("])` but it's not the case.

Is there a way to write value on new property from .kv file ?

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    ChoiceList:
        text_list: ["Apple","Orange","Banana"]
'''

class ChoiceList(BoxLayout):
    text_list = ListProperty(["WHY  DEFAULT PARAMETER IS STILL HERE :("])

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for text in self.text_list:
            print(text)

class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.box = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.box

App().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Kivy Discord](https://discord.gg/PDJaCnMC):

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ListProperty

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    ChoiceList:
        text_list: ["Apple","Orange","Banana"]
'''

class ChoiceList(BoxLayout):
    text_list = ListProperty(["WHY  DEFAULT PARAMETER IS STILL HERE :("])

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        super().on_kv_post(base_widget)
        for text in self.text_list:
            print(text)

class App(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.box = Builder.load_string(KV)
        return self.box

App().run()
```